# Uninstall of XAMPP fails at "No script engine for file extension"

Tags: uninstall, xampp

While uninstalling XAMPP it shows the following errors:

> Input Error: There is no script engine for file extension ".vbs".
>
> XAMPP uninstall not OK
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

How do I uninstall it?

Answer (score 0):

If you've not installed any program from it as service (MySQL or Apache), you can stop the server by running `C:\xampp\xampp_stop.exe` and remove the directory `C:\xampp` (or whatever you've installed XAMPP to).